# Anime where the first episode is about a 10 years old homeless boy

Tags: story-identification, anime

I am looking for a manga from 2010-2015.

Context: I always watch at least the first 3 episodes of a series before judging it. In a recent conversation about the worst anime scene, I remember an anime with a quite recent look and feel that was labelled as "Horrible" in my mind.

The following scenes are from the first 3 episodes, they are related from how good I remember them instead of speculative chronological order.

- A homeless 10 years old boy travels with the corpse of his dead grandad folded in half in a trolley. After inserting is freshly licked finger in the wound trying to patch the hole in his chest.
- His grandpa wants to teach him a last lesson hugging him really strong while he turns cold. The boy is completely lost and doesn't understand the concept of death so he travels around the town asking for help without crying. It's night and raining heavily. Every one rejects or ignores him.
- The homeless boy asks for money every time someone needs help as a salary.
- He is adopted by a lady that works at night.
- His new mother get shoot as he refuse to kill her.

Those scenes are not related to the plot but act as a character introduction.

The main theme of the series is about hero fighting crime in suit and mecha. 
With a pinch of inner evil. The series plot look flat in my mind so it's not a blockbuster.

The hero(homeless kid) has a black organic like suit that cover him. While the meca in the openning scene is white with some light blue. They seems to team up as they apear side by side in the openning.

The main opening song is annoying as hell, weird rap, off tempo.

Comment: FWIW is this actually an anime you're looking for or a manga because you mention both?

Comment: Knights of Sidonia has the mechs and the dead grandfather, but Nagate leaves the body behind when he rejoins civilization.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, 100% anime. with opening song and everything. But I miss used manga, as most anime are from manga.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, It's not futurist mecha. No space or anything involved. Just insect/animal like monster in japan.

Comment: You mention "suit and Mecha" in your question. Are these magical or biological constructs?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, nice catch I was editing sketch of their hair in the question but this maybe more valuable. Both! Two things a black organik suite that cover the homeless hero. a generic white meca suite size of an human not house tall, the white meca is from the opening spoil but it looked friendly..

Comment: It's look like a copy of [devil man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devilman) of some kind. Hero is black fuzzy hair. His firend his white hair and rich like [Ryo Asuka](https://static.tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pub/images/crybaby_ryo_3.png). They fight evilish monster that hide in human form..

Comment: This sounds like the sort of cheerful, upbeat drama I need to help me start off the new year on a positive note.

Comment: @Valorum , You did it! Thanks to your keyword "drama", I narrowed the search to [this](https://myanimelist.net/manga.php?q=&type=0&score=0&status=0&mid=0&sm=0&sd=0&sy=0&em=0&ed=0&ey=0&c%5B%5D=a&c%5B%5D=b&c%5B%5D=c&c%5B%5D=f&gx=0&genre%5B%5D=1&genre%5B%5D=8&genre%5B%5D=24&genre%5B%5D=37) and it's the last one!

Comment: @xdtTransform - Great, now post it as a self-answer!

Comment: And I was wrong grandpa is not dead look is head is in the fridge. [source](https://randomc.net/image/ZETMAN/ZETMAN%20-%2008%20-%2030.jpg)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is "[Zetman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zetman)" by Masakazu Katsura.

#### Synopsis:

> Jin is a strange kid with an angel mark on his hand. He lives a poor but peaceful life with his grandfather, along with the other destitute and abandoned vagabonds near the river. One day, his peaceful life changes when a strange monster named "player" appears, chopping off heads and killing everyone who appears in front of it.

#### Matching clues in chronological order:

In the first episode we have:

1. A 10 year old homeless boy.
   [image]
2. Helping people for money.
   [image]
3. Coming home he find his grandfather dying and try to patch him with his freshly licked finger poking the hole in his chest.
   [image]
4. So he fold his grandfather in half in a trolley and seeks for help
   [image]
5. He gets adopted by a lady working at a night bar
   [image]
6. The Mech suit.
   [image]
7. The biological suit.
   [image]

And the weird opening music: dot dot dot dot dot ..

I finally found it by realizing it was a "drama" and doing [this search](https://myanimelist.net/manga.php?q=&type=0&score=0&status=0&mid=0&sm=0&sd=0&sy=0&em=0&ed=0&ey=0&c%5B%5D=a&c%5B%5D=b&c%5B%5D=c&c%5B%5D=f&gx=0&genre%5B%5D=1&genre%5B%5D=8&genre%5B%5D=24&genre%5B%5D=37) for genres of Action, Drama, Sci-Fi, and Supernatural.

Comment: Good work! You will be able to accept your self-answer 48 hours after having first asked about it, and you really ought to do so.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, you and valorum help a lot your question helped me put word on vague memories.  Action, Drama, Sci-Fi, Supernatural were the tag that help reduce the search.

Comment: Hi, could you please self-accept your answer?